# JPA with subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm quite new to JPA. I recently learned how to do relationships between classes but not sure what to do when it comes to having subclasses and relationships between parents and children.

Here is my problem and I what I want to end up with...

I have an abstract class, Product. The Product will contain fields common to all products (it will have a product_id, name, description and price).
Extending from Product, I have Book. Book has one more attribute which is author.
Also extending from Product is Shirt. Shirt also has a specific attribute which is size.

So I want the database to look like this:

========

PRODUCT
product_id (pk),
name,
description,
price

========

=========

BOOK
product_id (pk fk),
author

=========

=========

SHIRT
product_id (pk fk),
size

==========

As you can see, the primary key in book and shirt will be product_id, which is also the foreign key to product. There is a one to one relationship between book and product. Also a one to one relationship between shirt and product.

I've found a couple of tutorials but they didn't explain it very well and weren't very useful for this particular problem.

Thanks in advance, appreciate any help.

EDIT:

Still really stuck on this after trying out what I found on github by Kevin Bowersox.
Here is my code for Product:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "EPOS_Product")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="POST_TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Product {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "product_id")
protected int id;

@Column(name = "name")
protected String name;

@Column(name = "price")
protected double price;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

The code in Shirt:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EPOS_Product")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Shirt")
public class Shirt extends Product{

@Column(name="size")
private String size;

public Shirt(){}

public Shirt(String name, double price, String size){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.size = size;       
}

public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}
```

}

And the code in Book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EPOS_Product")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Book")
public class Book extends Product{

private String author;

public Book(){}

public Book(String name, double price, String author){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.author = author;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
```

}

I also tried changing the table names in book and shirt to "EPOS_Book" and "EPOS_Shirt" and still got an error. I get:

SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update.

And:

BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification.

This is the query it tries to run:

Hibernate: 
    select
        hibernate_sequence.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    select
        hibernate_sequence.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        EPOS_Product
        (name, price, author, POST_TYPE, product_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, 'Book', ?)

Answer (score 0):

In JPA an inheritance relationship is modeled using the `@Inheritance` annotation and a strategy for storing the entities.  Given your current data model I would lean towards the table per class strategy.

Essentially you will wind up with:

- A table and entity for each derived class. The abstract class does **not** receive its own table.
- An `@Inheritance` annotation on the abstract class with a strategy defined. `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`

One misconception you may have regarding this strategy is that the `Product` class is to be persisted in the database.  Instead the fields in the product class should be duplicated in the `Book` and `Shirt` tables.

For a tutorial on table per class see my blog: http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/22

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't watch the video in work though, I will have a watch this evening.
So on Product... Do I still need to put Entity and Table annotations on? And on Book and Shirt... do these classes also need the Inheritance annotation?

Comment: @Chris Hope it helps.  The code is also on GitHub.  The entity annotations are definitely required.  The table annotation is not required if your tables meet JPA default naming standards.  I can never remember the exact standard so I explicitly add the `@Table` annotation.  The abstract class is the only class that will need `@Inheritance`

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I downloaded the code from Github. I still can't get it working and have spent a lot of time on it. I've posted some code above, as an edit to the original question... can you see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Chris I don't believe you need a `DiscriminatorColumn`

Comment: @Chris did you have any luck?

Comment: Nope. :/ I tried it as above but without DiscriminatorColumn and still just got exceptions

Comment: @Chris Product should not have a table, while shirt and book should have separate tables.  Have you watched the video?  It should explain everything.

Comment: Okay, tried that and it still doesn't work. I still didn't watch the video because for the task I was working on, I just reverted to standard JDBC. Now I've finished the whole task so I'm going back to trying to get JPA working again. So I will watch the video tonight.(again, can't right on, in work). It still doesn't work. The annotations I have on Product are ENTITY and INHERITANCE(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE). And COLUMN on all the fields and @Id on the ID field. On Book and Shirt, I have ENTITY and TABLE(name="EPOS_Book/Shirt"). And COLUMN again.

Comment: Continued: And the stacktrace I got when trying to persist a shirt and book is:
"BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" and "SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update" and "RollbackException: Error whilst commiting the transaction"

Comment: And just thought to add the query it is trying to run. It's trying to insert into Product even though I called the tables EPOS_Book and EPOS_Shirt. The query: INSERT INTO Product (name, price, author, DTYPE, product_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'Book', ?)